# Overflow:hidden equivalent for movieclip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have imported movieclip on my stage. But this movieclip has objects which lay out of borders  of this movieclip, so I've got part of objects on stage which must be invisible, but they are not invisible.

My MovieClip in player(player cuts off some peaces of pictures)

[image: My movie clip in player]

My MovieClip imported in another

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you want, but have you tried creating a mask?

```
var mask:Sprite = new sprite();
mask.graphics.beginFill(0xffffff);
mask.graphics.drawRect(0,0,desiredWidth,desiredHeight);
mask.graphics.endFill();

mask.x = loadedClip.x; 
mask.y = loadedClip.y;
addChild(mask);
loadedClip.mask = mask;
```

Comment: Thank you.It works but there must be mask.graphics.drawRect and mask.graphics.endFill()